# что возвращает getLayoutInflater ()?

Tags: android

```
getLayoutInflater ()    
Returns
LayoutInflater The shared LayoutInflater.
```

и что это значит ?

допустим что делает эта строка ?

```
LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: Это строка делает точно то, что написано в документации - возвращает ```LayoutInflater```. Что вы еще хотите узнать?

Comment: пример кода с http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/80-urok-40-layoutinflater-uchimsja-ispolzovat.html     Вопрос как getLayoutInflater()   понимает  какой LayoutInflater нужен и с какими параметрами?     почему там не пишется LayoutInflater ltInflater  = new   LayoutInflater (...)

Comment: Потому, что `LayoutInflater` нельзя создавать через конструктор, т. к. это системный сервис.